# In R topicmodels package, how could we get the topics' distributions over terms?

Tags: r, lda, topicmodels

I'm running LDA by using topicmodels package.

```
lda.model = LDA(dtm, k,control = list(em = list(iter.max = 1000, tol = 10^-4)))
apps.terms<-terms(lda.model,15)
head(apps.terms)

    Topic.1 Topic.2 Topic.3 Topic.4 Topic.5
1      38      55     187      38      38
2      40      38     171      40      35
3      55      35     178      56      44
4      49      49      74      35      55
5      35      44     177     190      52
6      44      53      80      55      49
```

These code get the 15 terms order by their proportion. If I didn't badly understand the LDA algorithm. Each topic is a distribution over terms.So I want to know the exact distribution over these terms. For example. Topic.1 is 30% related to 38, 20% related to 40 ..etc. Is there any way to get it by using `topicmodels` package?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the posterior probabilities for each document.

```
lda.inf <- posterior(lda.model,dtm)
```

Comment: What is the significance of the order of the Topics?

Comment: No sure if this package sorts the topics. But usually there is no significance to the order of the topics.